# Getting 9009 error while executing C++ in geany

Tags: c++, geany

I'm new to programming world, when I typed my code in  geany and executed it, it gives an error like in this image.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should attach the errors that occurred in a code block in your question instead of as screenshots.

Comment: the code is very simple. `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 cout  << "Hello  world";
 return 0;
}
`

Comment: No. You should attach the occurring error(s) that are relevant to your question as verbatim in your question's text. Screenshots may be taken down eventually and thus information and the usefulness of the question will be diminished.

Comment: Look at your comment.  Is the code readable?  Please **edit** your question with the code.

Comment: When you searched the internet for "geany error 9009", what came up?  Please **edit** your question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to compile your code. Geany is an editor with functions of an IDE, but for using C++ with Geany you will need to follow these steps:

1. Install a C++-compiler on your Widnows
2. Hack your code and save it e.g. as test.cpp
3. Ensure Geany knows about your C++ compiler by checking/changing settings via Build->Set Build Commands
4. Compile your code/build your code by e.g. hitting F9
5. Start your program

I assume you missed at least point 4.